# Making a live CD of my ubuntu install

Tags: customization

i want to make a CD of current ubuntu install. I wanna make a live CD/DVD that, when installed, install my custom system, while allowing the user to enter their details like password , use name, and time format. IT should be easy using the OEM installer, but i wanna distribute the iso. can anyone tell me how to do that. (I would prefer a GUI tool rather than command line.
thanks

Comment: This link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=688872 describes how to create Live CD/DVD from your installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ubuntu customization kit. It gaves the possibility to install you preferred applications. You can create an iso file also.

Comment: Thanks ferit, i already did that with remastersys. and thanks for suggesting UCK. it went great